# Error while placing email data into excel sheet

Tags: excel, vb.net, outlook

I have been trying to make a bot that runs a macro in excel using VB that takes all my emails from a specified date and places the subject, sender, their email, and the body message in a excel sheet, but I have been having an error that I dont know how to solve, I also dont have much experience with this language tbh, The error I am getting is: “run-time error 13 – Type mismatch”
The error is at the end `Next OMAIL`
Thanks to any help in advance

```
Sub OUTLOOK_IMPORT_EMAILBOT()

Dim O As Outlook.Application
Set O = New Outlook.Application

Dim ONS As Outlook.Namespace
Set ONS = O.GetNamespace("MAPI")


Dim MYFOL As Outlook.Folder
Set MYFOL = ONS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim OMAIL As Outlook.MailItem
Set OMAIL = O.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim i As Long
'R = 2
i = 1
For Each OMAIL In MYFOL.Items
If OMAIL.ReceivedTime >= Range("email_Receipt_Date").Value Then

    Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OMAIL.Subject
    Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
    Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop

    Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OMAIL.ReceivedTime
    Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
    Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop

    Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OMAIL.SenderName
    Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
    Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop

    Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Value = OMAIL.Body
    Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
    Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop



    'Range(R, 1).Value = OMAIL.ReceivedTime
    'Range(R, 2).Value = OMAIL.SenderEmailAddress
    'Range(R, 3).Value = OMAIL.Body
    
    'R = R + 1
    i = i + 1
    End If
    
    Next OMAIL
    
    Set MYFOL = Nothing
    Set ONS = Nothing
    Set O = Nothing
    


End Sub
```

Comment: It's because `MYFOL` doesn't contain a collection of `Outlook.MailItem`s. `Set OMAIL = O.CreateItem(olMailItem)` is superfluous - creating a new email. If you remove it the error will occur on the For ... Each line.

Comment: Also looks to me like you've either copied an very old example some of that syntax you've got there is either vb6 or vba.

Comment: I watched a youtube video on how to do it tbh I dont really use vb at all just needed to do this as for a side project